# Where is _NFILE defined

Tags: c

To create a daemon I have read somewhere that in order to close all the open file descriptors we can use the following code:-

```
for (fd = 0; fd < _NFILE; fd++)
  close(fd); /* close all file descriptors */
```

I have to define _NFILE as

```
#define _NFILE 3
```

or is it already defined in some include files?
I tried to grep it in the /usr/include directory but could not find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_NFILE` only applies to original Unix.  The portable way to do this is `sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX)` (POSIX).

Comment: Thanks geek. one curious question. I have read the man page for sysconf. The maximum number of files that a process can have open at anytime.  Must not be less than _POSIX_OPEN_MAX (20). But when I printed the value on my terminal I got 1024. Shall I assume that the 1024 file descriptors are opened for my terminal?

Comment: The number of files actually open is not portably available, only a high water mark for how many *could* be open.  (Most systems with `/proc` will let you determine easily what file descriptors are open, although details vary between those systems so this cannot be considered portable.)

Comment: sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX) will only tell you a bound on new file descriptors. There may be file descriptors open with a larger value. This call will not help with closing all open file descriptors.

Comment: @Richard, it is, nevertheless, the closest thing to a standard available. The hard limit on `getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE)` is more correct — but even then the process may have opened files and then lowered the hard limit, so technically there still may be files beyond it, and only inspection of kernel structures (via `/proc`, `lsof`, etc.) is 100% precise. This may qualify as self-destructive overthinking of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[This stdio.h](http://www2.hs-fulda.de/~klingebiel/c-stdlib/stdio.h.htm) says that

> - The value of _NFILE is defined in the Processor Specific ABI.  The value
> - is chosen for historical reasons rather than for truly processor related
> - attribute.  Note that the SPARC Processor Specific ABI uses the common
> - UNIX historical value of 20 [...].

Then goes on to define some values based on the machine architecture